# Returning Lat/Long from Google Maps API v3 to original page from click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have a latitude and longitude field on this project I'm working on.  I'm trying to consolidate the need to external information sources and trying to incorporate Google Maps API into this project.  I'm a complete n00b to JavaScript and Google Maps API.  The goal I have is for you to click a link which opens a new window and displays a Google Map.  You then scroll around, zoom, etc. to find what you want, then click, the window closes and the lat/long magically is populated on the original page.  I'd also like to have the map display markers for existing ones that have been click from the database.  I've been following this https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 and have now added Lat/Long fields at the bottom.  It's been recommended that I use

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
```

But, because I'm a n00b, I have no idea where to put that code to work within the code block from the tutorial:

```
function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("getdata.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
        document.getElementById("latbox").value = this.getPosition().lat();
        document.getElementById("lngbox").value = this.getPosition().lng();
    });

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
    function doNothing() {}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 1024px; height: 800px"></div>
    <input type="text" name="latFld" id="latFld" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="lngFld" id="lngFld" /><br />

  </body>
</html>
```